# How to discover and connect bluetooth devices with xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, xamarin.forms, sodaq-mbili

A short explanation. I'm working on a school project where i use xamarin forms to develop a cross-platform app. With the app is should be able to lock or unlock our smartLock (for a bike).

I'm using the Xamarin.BluetoothLE package. I've successfully started a scan for devices. But that's the only thing i figured out how it works.

Is there anybody with experience in this area who is able to help me?
I would like to pair my device through the app with our SODAQ-Mbili board. And then i should send "lock" or "unlock" when i press the button.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can follow this guide [link](https://greenfinch.ie/blog/2016-07-06-bluetoothLE.html) .Here is [demo](https://github.com/tbrushwyler/Xamarin.BluetoothLE)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links and the info, i've also found them and tried to implement them. I managed to create an IAdapter. So i can acces the BluetoothAdapter, i also can scan for devices. But I'm stuck on the part where you add the found devices to a list. On the link you posted, they create a private function, but i get errors on the DeviceList. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: App.xaml.cs
http://imgur.com/xakEJEb
LoginPage.xaml.cs
http://imgur.com/jLGieHy

Comment: I also encountered the same problem.

Comment: Before using `Xamarin.BluetoothLE`,please excute `DependencyService.Register<>()` method manually register each dependency service defined in the Droid and IOS  projects, and then you can call the interface method successfully.

Comment: App Delegate : http://imgur.com/3YTzGkQ 
MainActivity : http://imgur.com/zjU5u8Z

I've already executed this in Android and IOS.